# Retrofit - ensuring observable calls always complete without a subscription

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I have an app that consumes a restful API and I am using Retrofit with RxJava to achieve this. The UI uses the MVVM pattern, leveraging the Android Data Binding library. The view models are what make requests to the API by using a class called `DataManager` which delegates calls to the appropriate service to return an `Observable` which the view model then subscribes to and handles the response. So far, it's working absolutely fantastically except for one thing. The subscriptions are essentially bound to the view model which is in turn bound to a `Fragment` so when the user navigates away from the screen, all subscriptions (which I maintain in a `CompositeSubscription`) are unsubscribed to prevent memory leaks. Now, by nature of the way that the `RxJavaCallAdapterFactory` this means that the underlying `Call` gets cancelled, meaning that the API request is cancelled. Now in most cases this is no problem, if the user navigates away from the page that is still loading, cancelling the call makes sense. (I should note at this point that my `Fragments` retain their state across configuration changes so the issue only occurs once the fragment is completely destroyed due to the user navigating away from it). However there are certain cases in my app where I want calls to persist regardless of whether or not any subscriptions are subscribed to it.

After some research I see that observables have `cache()` and `replay()` methods that allow them to emit their data regardless of whether or not they are subscribed to. This is good, but it only solves half of the problem for me. The observables only exist in the view model, so once it's garbage collected the observables will be too, meaning that the calls die (surely? If I'm wrong about that please let me know). So I need a way of retaining references to cached observables and only removing them once they have fully completed their request.

My idea at the moment is to have a singleton class that would retain a collection of observables to be cached in memory. These observables would then remove themselves from the list when `onComplete` has been called.

```
public class ObservableCache {
    private static final ObservableCache INSTANCE = new ObservableCache();

    private final List<Observable<?>> cache;

    public static ObservableCache instance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public ObservableCache() {
        cache = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void cacheObservable(Observable<?> observable) {
        cache.add(observable.cache().doOnCompleted(() -> cache.remove(observable)));
    }
}
```

I would just like to get some thoughts on how I should approach solving this issue as well as how viable my suggested approach is. I can't help but feel like there is something wrong with it, but I can't quite figure out what...

Comment: take a look, maybe it helps http://blog.bradcampbell.nz/rxjava-handling-configuration-changes-with-request-observables/

Comment: @RalphBergmann Thanks, but that doesn't really address my issue. I'm already following what that article suggests (although using MVVM rather than MVP).